# Getting pyttsx3 ModuleNotFoundError error, can't use pyttsx3

Tags: python, module

I am working on an ai project but I am not able to use pyttsx3. First I installed pyttsx3

1. first I installed pyttsx3 and wrote pip install pyttsx3
2. it gave me error

   > ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cg4iec95\comtypes\setup.py'"'"'; file='"'"'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cg4iec95\comtypes\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(file);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, file, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-rqpb37yj\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\Include\comtype
3. Then I wrote  **pip install -U pyttsx3==2.71** and it got successfully installed
4. In my code I typed **import pyttsx3** but it gave me an error

   ```
    File "c:/Users/User/Desktop/Sushant Code/JARVIS/JARVIS.py", line 1, in <module>
      import pyttsx3
   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyttsx3
   ```
5. And now when I wrote pip install pyttsx3 it said

   > Requirement already satisfied: pyttsx3 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (2.71)
   > Requirement already satisfied: pypiwin32; "win32" in sys_platform in c:\users\user\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from pyttsx3) (223)
   > Requirement already satisfied: pywin32>=223 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from pypiwin32; "win32" in sys_platform->pyttsx3) (228)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Are your working in a virtual environment? Then you need to first activate it! Otherwise try:

- open command line
- cd to your site-packages folder (if using a virtual environment first activate that!)
- Then type `python -m pip install pyttsx3`

Python actually searches through the site-packages folder but when it isn't installed there, Python can't actually find it! Hope that worked for you, otherwise, add a comment!

Answer (score -1):

If you are on a mac then try pip3 install pyttsx3 - macOS doesn’t allow pip for python3 - you have to use pip3 to install mac . If that doesn’t work then try reading the pyttsx3 documentation by PyPi , - they will help with the trouble shooting process from here - https://pypi.org/project/pyttsx3/
HTH !!!

Comment: This is not correct. MacOS doesn’t specifically disallow `pip`. Multiple Python installations can exist and they all an have their own `pip` command. The `pipX` and `pipX.Y` aliases for the same script (with X and Y the major and minor version numbers of the Python installation they are part of) are helpful extra names to help distinguish between them but which one is found is just a question of your `PATH` configuration.

Comment: Try running `which -a pip` instead and you’ll find what various `pip` commands are present on your command path...

Comment: Oh ok sorry - I am new to python so forgive me if I was mistaken. (: